# 2-SAT Problem with additional constraints on variable?

Tags: complexity-theory

Given a 2-SAT problem that is satisfiable. The solution to the problem can be found in polynomial time.

Adding an additional constraint:

1. The maximum number of positive literals that can have the boolean Value 1 is N. (i.e. a=positive literal, ~a=negative literal)

Is the problem still solvable in Polynomial time?

My assumption is it should be but I am unclear now to modify the original solution? Or are we looking at something similar to the Vertex Cover Problem?

Comment: MAX-2SAT is NP-hard, so your problem (which I don't quite understand) is probably not in P.

Comment: Much thanks. The problem is satisfiable. Thus we can easily solve it. But the solution is required to have an additional constraint that it can have at most N 1's. For example lets assume that all of the following solutions to a given hypothetical 4 variable problem are valid: (1) A=0, B=0, C=1, D=0 (2) A=1, B=0, C=0, D=1 (3) A=0, B=0, C=0, D=1. If N=1 is the condition only (1) and (3) can be valid solutions but not (2).

Comment: Right, it's not MAX-2SAT. Minimum weight 2SAT is probably also NP-hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is NP-hard by reduction from [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover), even when there are no negative literals.

If you meant to count by occurrences rather than just bounding the number of

distinct variables which are true, then use [this paper](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~feige/TechnicalReports/VertexCover.ps)'s result and [this paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-the-hardness-of-approximating-minimum-vertex-co-Safra/46e49432fc6c360376cad11367c6d2411fb3e0ea)'s result.